# Is it possible to select $(this) + $('#Example')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to select with jQuery the `$(this)` + `$('#Example')`?

Something like `$(this, '#Example')`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$(this).add('#Example')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method of jquery - see demo below:

```js
$('.click').on('click',function(){
  $(this).add('#example').css('color','red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="click">Click here</div>
<div id="example">Example</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not combine in one string different elements with `this`. So your example `$(this, '#Example')` will not work. But you can point any other element in one like `$('.element1, .element2, #element3')`

And according comment bellow I recommend you use 'add' method with other elements. [Here is codepen](http://codepen.io/dd-tch/pen/dNGLER) for you

Comment: idk who downvoted this but it's perfectly accurate. you can still use the `add` method to add elements to a jquery object containing "this"